# Show Few data into Table and run web service in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have one problem, i fetch data from one URL and set it to Table but if data is almost 10 to 15 values. then i get data in table easily means table data populated in less time.

But if Data is almost 500 to 600 values then one have to wait till all data come as i have used **ProgressView** so user have to wait till all response doesn't come.

is there is any way to resolve this, to set some data earlier and then after all data that i have got afterwards.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can create your own custom queue and fetch a server request on it and when response receive then you can reload your table view in main queue..or main thread

Comment: is it possible to get data in Chunk. from Web services

Comment: Yes you can use alamofire for the web services request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use pagination support in your tableView and in your backend as well, please see this example:
https://easyiostechno.wordpress.com/2014/11/14/pagination-of-table-views/

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's a bad practice to fetch large data at once and keep user waiting. You should ideally fetch data only when it's necessary. For your case I would suggest you to use **paging mechanism**.

Below is just **rough idea about paging** which you can use:

1. When you load your data from `webservice`, send two parameters named
   `PAGE_COUNT and PREVIOUS_PAGE_COUNT.`
2. For first time send  `PAGE_COUNT = nuber_of_values_you_want_to_fetch_initially and PREVIOUS_PAGE_COUNT
   = 0`
3. When user scrolls down showing loader at the bottom of table and again hit webservice but with `PREVIOUS_PAGE_COUNT = nuber_of_values_you_want_to_fetch_initially + PAGE_COUNT`
4. This approach will need some modification from back-end also like checking for initial page count and then fetching next records from
   database.

I hope this will help you.